# Azure WebJobs Node.js version

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

For a Azure `Web App`, we have set environment `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` to `6.3.0` and also specified the node engine in `www-server/package.json`:

```
"engines": {
  "node": "6.x.x",
  "npm": "3.x.x"
}
```

This seems fine - `process.versions.node` shows that our `Web App` is using node `6.3.0`.

However `WebJobs` on the same `Web App` instance seems to use Node `5.9.1` instead of `6.3.0`. (We are using [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Host.exe](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki#option-2-no-http-functionwebhook-support) Queue Trigger)

How do we set the node version for Azure `WebJobs`? We need at-least `6.1.0`

Comment: I test a nodejs `webjob` with simple script `console.log(process.versions.node)`, it works fine on my side. What's your entire application looks like?

Comment: @[Gary Liu](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4989668/gary-liu-msft) `process.versions.node` gives you a version > `5.9.1`?

Comment: `6.3.0`, as I set of `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` at `App settings`

Comment: I verified that `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` is set to `6.3.0` but when a node script is run via the `WebJob`, `process.versions.node` gives version `5.9.1`. I'm not sure what's wrong. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Are you using azure webjob SDK to invoke the node.js script but leveraging original pure Azure Web Apps' node.js environment?

Comment: We are using [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Host.exe](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki#option-2-no-http-functionwebhook-support) Queue Trigger, which I think is based on webjob SDK.

Comment: Does your webjob's structure looks like the image at https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki#option-2-no-http-functionwebhook-support ? If so, could you find the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Host.exe.config` file in the `bin` folder? What's value of the `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` under `appSettings` tag in this file?

Comment: Yes, my structure is exactly as per the url you mentioned. I reviewed `wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\continuous\ScriptHost\bin\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Host.exe.config`. It did not contain the variable `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION`. So I add it: `<appSettings>
<other config stuff.../>
<add key="WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION" value="6.3.0" />
</appSettings>`. `process.versions.node` is still 5.9.1. I also restarted the `WebApp` as well as the `WebJob` but it did not work.

Comment: A basic `WebJob` without using `ScriptHost` correctly runs with node `6.3.0`. So, I guess this issue is related to [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Host.exe](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki#option-2-no-http-functionwebhook-support)

Comment: [@Gary Liu](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4989668/gary-liu-msft) - thanks for your suggestions. I tried a few things but the problem still exists. In your setup does changing `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION ` in  `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.‌​Host.exe.config` work correctly?  Was [your earlier successful test script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717013/azure-webjobs-node-js-version?noredirect=1#comment64845679_38717013) built using [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Host.exe](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki#option-2-no-http-functionwebhook-support)?

Comment: No, I didn't configured  `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.‌​Host.exe.config` and I use common step to deploy webjob: zip the javascript script into a package, and upload it from Azure portal.

Comment: And I have involved senior engineers to help us about this issue. I will come back when I get any update from them. Appreciate your patience.

Comment: Hey guys - I suggest you take this to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) - this isn't the place to have a discussion.

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT could the engineers give a heads up about this. i.e. Using [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Host.exe](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki#option-2-no-http-functionwebhook-support) with node version >= `6.x.x`. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidMakogon not intended to be a discussion. Just trying to get an answer.

Comment: @Kayo But... it's a discussion. And you're now asking follow-up questions here as well, which should be posted as *separate questions*. Or discuss in Chat.

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT I've moved this Q. to [this chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121683/azure-webjobs-scripthost-node-version)